# Can API request be made outside the redux slice files?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

I am new to `Redux toolkit`. I have watched some tutorials and read some articles and tried checking out documentations, I can't seem to find if it is possible to make your API requests outside the `Redux toolkit slice files`. As a beginner, I would like to make the API calls on each component that need them instead of fetching the API inside the `Redux slice file` and `dispatch` in the component that needs it.
For example, I have a `userSlice` feature in `Redux toolkit`, I made API request to update one of the stores state which is called `userCart`. I have a component where I dispatched this request. I would like to know if there is a way I can write the exact API request code inside the component? Here is my code sample:
This API call inside the `userSlice`:

```
const initialState={
  token: null,
  loading: false,
  error: false,
  success: false,
  userDetails: {},
  userCart: {},
  userAddress:{}
 }


  //update cart
  export const updateCart = createAsyncThunk('updateCart', async(data, thunkAPI)=>{
  const {cartId, userId, foodId} = data
  try {
    const res = await axios.patch(`${BASE_URL}/cart/${cartId}`, {
        userId: userId,
        foodId: foodId
    }, 
    {withCredentials: true,
    headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}}
    )

    return res.data
} catch (error) {
    
}
})

const userSlice = createSlice({
name: 'user',
initialState,
reducers:{//codes }
extraReducers:{//codes}
)}
```

In cart component, I simply dispatched the action:

```
const handleCartUpdate =()=>{
   dispatch(updateCart(data))
  }
```

It is a react native app. Why I don't like this present format is that the `userSlice` can really get messy with lots of API request codes. For instance, the API request to handle user is also located inside this file, the API to handle user address is also located there, same as cart, etc. I know that I can have different slice for each but that is like adding more files to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The *best* answer, and the approach that we recommend, is to actually use our "RTK Query" data fetching and caching API to make requests, rather than writing the thunks, reducers, and effects for data fetching yourself:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

If you are writing the request logic and thunks yourself: I'm not sure whether you're asking about where the *code* for those thunks should live (in a slice file vs somewhere else), or where/how to actually *dispatch* the thunks.

Note that you *should* have many different slice files in your app, to manage different types of data:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic